# Convert from seconds to minutes in Open Office

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

I have several cells with a time value in seconds e.g (23, 102, 543, ...)

I am not very familiar with the formula functions in Open Office. *How do I address the same Cell-Box with the value in it?* I want to replace all the second-values in that cell with a minute format (102seconds = 1:42).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a spare row or column of your spreadsheet that lines up with the existing data, enter the following formula:

```
=TIME(0;0;A1)
```

Where *A1* is the cell with the time in seconds.  That function takes hours, minutes, and seconds as parameters and converts it into OpenOffice's regular time format.

Then, copy or drag to autofill the rest of the cells that are necessary to perform the calculation on all the relevant data.  Now, highlight all the newly calculated values, right-click and choose *Cut* or press CTRL+X, then highlight the old values and right-click and choose *Paste Special*.  Uncheck *Paste all* and then uncheck everything but *Date & time* and click okay.

Finally, right click on the whole set of cells, choose *Format Cells*, select *Time* under *Category* and select whichever format you desire.